# How to create msi project for more than 1 projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, installation

it is very easy to make a msi project for any single project ..
but my question is that, i want to make a msi project that contains 2 Existing Project and 1 SQL SERVER Setup within it.

i want to install SQL SERVER from msi then install 2 exe .. 
Please give me any suggestion or reference .

Thank You

Answer (score 6):

DONT DO IT. Point. Installing SQL Server rom within an MSI is not supported for the obvious problem of updating it.

Comment: THat you should learn how to write MSI first - from the installer documentation. Slaving sub-installs is not recommended because you can not update the sub-isntalled item independently. So, installing SQL Server from WTITHIN the MSI as part of it is an antipattern. Getting you fired level of bad design. I suggest learning how MSI operate, and then moving over to WIX.

Comment: "I know how to make msi for single project" - no, boiling water is not cooking. You obviously from your wording and what you attmempt to do do NOT know how to make a VALID and BEST PRACTICE msi from a proejct. Getting it somehow install is one reason so many oftware out there is crappy in the isntall experience.

Answer (score 2):

You should divide the problem to:

1. Installing the prerequisites.

   You'll have to use a Bootstrapper to initiate Microsoft SQL Server's installer before starting your own MSI package. For example, take a look at [dotnetinstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/) project.
2. Installing your application.

   To merge more than one project in a single installer, check the following question: [How to deploy multiple projects in a single MSI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295138/how-to-deploy-multiple-projects-in-a-single-msi)